# why the session is out unexpectedly in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net website, which use MVC 1.0 framework, but I found sometimes it will lost the current session unexpectedly, but I can not find the cause of this problem .

Do anyone have any suggestions ? or tell me how can find the reason of this issue,

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what sessionstate mode are you using? inproc, stateserver, or sqlserver?

Comment: where can i see my current sessionstate mode ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you haven't explicitly set this in your web.config, then you would be using inproc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause is that the IIS worker process is recycling for some reason.  When this happens, and you are using inproc session, you will lose your session variables.

http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/09/19/Why_do_I_lose_ASP_Session_State_on_IIS6.aspx

This is because the session data is stored in the worker process memory.  On the other hand, if you use an out of process session server then your session data is stored elsewhere (SQL Server database for example) and it doesn't matter if the worker process restarts.

You can tweak settings in IIS to minimize the worker process from restarting so much.

Comment: I am pondering about:

System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { smtp.Send(mailMessage); });

I use this to send email, whether or not this will cause the threads out and session out ?